# What do I change 10.10.29.0/24 to in my Postgres server?

Tags: postgresql

I am setting a server up with my Raspberry Pi running Rasbian OS by Debian and the SQL I am planning to use is PostgreSQL.

What I am hoping to do is create a server where I can save peoples information when they sign up. I have connected to the Raspberry Pi remotely on my mac and now *I am stuck*.

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

And it told me to edit a file with this:

```
host all all 10.10.29.0/24 trust
```

It includes that I should change the "10.10.29.0/24" part to something in my client's and network's range but I do not know what to change it to.

Also, when I edit the file, I do not know how to save it so if anyone knows how to go about that please do tell me.

Comment: The client is trying to connect from same location or different one?

Comment: Ask your network administrator.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan So I want the client to connect from a different location to my Raspberry Pi so I can store user sign ins.

Comment: So either you'ld have to add his IP address if it's personal or his router IP address if it's office.

Comment: Yes, as per my understanding and exprience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider looking at the [official documentation for the settings in pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.

This file is used by the PostgreSQL instance to determine how **hosts/computers/accounts** are allowed to connect to the **instance/database** via a certain **method**.

The first couple of lines from the example `pg_hba.conf` file in the official documentation are a good summary of how you can set the **access permissions** for a given PostgrSQL instance:

> ```
>  # Allow any user on the local system to connect to any database with
>  # any database user name using Unix-domain sockets (the default for local
>  # connections).
>  #
>  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
>  local   all             all                                     trust
>  
>  # The same using local loopback TCP/IP connections.
>  #
>  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
>  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
>  
>  # The same as the previous line, but using a separate netmask column
>  #
>  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            IP-ADDRESS      IP-MASK             METHOD
>  host    all             all             127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255     trust
>  
>  # The same over IPv6.
>  #
>  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
>  host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
> ```

Instead of replacing the entry `host all all 10.10.29.0/24 trust` as you pointed out in your question to something that matches your network configuration, just comment out the line and create a new line.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# host  all             all             10.10.29.0/24           trust
```

Let's say, if your server is running with an IP address of `10.112.19.24` and you only want the application located on the same server to access the `mydatabase` and you have a dedicated user for that database named `my_user`, then the line might look like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# host  all             all             10.10.29.0/24           trust
local   mydatabase      my_user                                 trust
```

No need to add an IP address. This line basically tells the PostgreSQL instance to allow a connection on the same server to access the `mydatabase` with the user `my_user`.

Now if somebody comes along from an external source (`10.112.19.26`)  and tries to access the same database (`mydatabase`) with the same user (`my_user`), then the access will be denied, because the source IP address would conflict with the configuration you just made.

You would have to add another IP address line or just allow a certain subnet to access the database. E.g.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# host  all             all             10.10.29.0/24           trust
local   mydatabase      my_user                                 trust
host    mydatabase      my_user         10.112.19.0/26          trust
```

The `10.112.19.0/26` is the CIDR notation of an IP range. In this case it resolve to:

```
first address: 10.112.19.0
last address:  10.112.19.63
subnet mask:   255.255.255.192
```

So anybody in that range could connect to your `mydatabase` with the user `my_user`.
Depending on your network configuration you might require a different CIDR notation.

#### Answering Your Question

> What do I change 10.10.29.0/24 to in my Postgres server?

1. Use either the `local ....`  configuration setting if the PostgreSQL instance is on the same server as your application.
2. If the database is located on a different host than the hosts connecting to the database, then use the `host ....`
   configuration setting, with an IP address that comes from the client range you are expecting.
3. If the connections are coming from a single host then you could use something like the following line:

   ```
   # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
   # host  all             all             10.10.29.0/24           trust
   local   mydatabase      my_user                                 trust
   host    mydatabase      my_user         10.112.19.13/32         trust # <<== THIS LINE
   ```

   This is basically telling the PostgreSQL instance to accept connections from one IP address. If your servers IP address that is connecting is `10.1.1.1` then the line becomes:

   ```
   host    mydatabase      my_user         10.1.1.1/32         trust
   ```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks John, I really do appreciate it.